# How to save command output to a file in windows and show output on terminal also?

Tags: windows, shell, command-line

I want to save output of a command in a file as well as display output on terminal.

For saving output to a file I am using following command:

```
>> ps -ef > D:\temp.txt
```

But this saves output into files but do not display on terminal. Which command should I use to perform both requirements?

Comment: I have the same problem, did you solved it? In my case even this (>) doesn't save output to a file. In unix/Linux I use 2>&1 | tee D:\temp.txt  but in windows that doesn't work.

Answer (score 0):

Use MinGW, and than use the following command:

```
ps -ef 2>&1 | tee D:\temp.txt
```

This will work.